# Selling software online

Tags: e-commerce

I am developing software which I want to sell online.  The typical pay the vender, get a digital key that unlocks the application scenario.

I've never set this up before, does anyone have any info on good service providers, and things I need to know when setting this up?

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft uses digital river, maybe check them out?

Comment: If Microsoft uses them, it sure is a safe bet.

Answer (score 1):

You can checkout a typical license acquisition [flow](https://github.com/Labs64/NetLicensing-FastSpring/wiki) using FastSpring 
[FastSpring / NetLicensing flow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GPU9f.png)

This combines FastSpring e-Commerce and NetLicensing license management.

Answer (score 0):

You did not say what language you are planning on using, but this is a great solution for a .net compiled language:
http://xheo.com/products/copy-protection

It provides two key features. First the ability to automatically generate your licenses based on many different ecommerce solutions so you don't have to keep paying a 3rd party a % for it.  Second, it offers code protection to prevent people from using Reflection on your software to crack it / steal your intellectual rights. (note i said prevent, not completely stop)

Answer (score 0):

I'm using FastSpring, you give them binary file and keys, and you setup your account to send an email that contains these two informations. you can tell them what you want and they will do it for you